# Issue when using sys and argv for command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from sys import argv

def multii():
    if len(argv) < 2:
        pass

    else:
        for value in values:
            if len(value) == argv[1]:
                print(value)

values = ["acehorrst", "hellorye", "badbadg", "skrskr", "hahahah"]

multii()
```

I invoked in the terminal as: "python3 "filename.py" 9"

so it would be: "python3 testargv.py 9"
and the it does nothing in the terminal

i thought 9 would be condiered argument 1, and there is "acehorrst" which is 9 letters long and it doesn't work, and I have the same issue with all the words, no matter what number I put.

Comment: start with print(argv) to see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to cast the argv to an integer. The line should be:

> if len(value) == int(argv[1]):

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is compare the length of the value to the integer value of the argument, by default the arguments are treated as strings.
So your execution of `python3 testargv.py 9` would make the `argv` look as follows
`['testargv.py', '9']`.

In your code you're comparing length to a string, convert the `argv[1]` to `int(argv[1])` and it'll work fine.

```
from sys import argv

def multii():
    if len(argv) < 2:
        pass

    else:
        for value in values:
            if len(value) == int(argv[1]):
                print(value)

values = ["acehorrst", "hellorye", "badbadg", "skrskr", "hahahah"]

multii()
```